# Keys not binding correctly to elements in D3

Tags: javascript, csv, svg, d3.js

I'm having trouble updating data after binding values to SVG elements using a key in D3.

Here's an illustration. This is a sample CSV file I'm using to track drilling sites in PA.

```
name,lat,lng,company,production
1,40.543401,-79.162257,Shell,20000
2,40.608186,-79.369354,Shell,40000
3,40.558923,-79.630966,Shell,10000
4,40.431514,-79.466171,Range,25000
5,40.439876,-80.015488,Range,26000
6,42.173455,-80.513306,CNX,30000
7,39.927082,-74.788055,CNX,120000
8,40.045964,-75.10962,Chesapeake,15000
9,40.822611,-77.839508,Chesapeake,16000
```

I bind this data to `g` elements using this code:

```
d3.csv("data.csv", type, function(error, data) {
    wells = chart.selectAll(".well")
      .data(data, function(d){ return d.name; }).enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "well")
      .attr("id", function(d){ return d.name })
      .attr("transform", function(d){ return "translate(" + projection([d.lng, d.lat])[0] + "," + projection([d.lng, d.lat])[1] + ")"; } );

    wells.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 4);
});
```

Note that the key I'm binding that data on is `name`.

Introduce data2.csv, which is practically identical except the unique id is called `well` instead of `name`, and two of the lat-lng pairs are switched.

```
well,lat,lng,company,production
100,40.543401,-79.162257,Shell,20000
2,40.608186,-79.369354,Shell,40000
3,40.558923,-79.630966,Shell,10000
4,40.431514,-79.466171,Range,25000
5,42.173455,-80.513306,Range,26000
6,40.439876,-80.015488,CNX,30000
7,39.927082,-74.788055,CNX,120000
8,40.045964,-75.10962,Chesapeake,15000
9,40.822611,-77.839508,Chesapeake,16000
```

When I rebind data and update, nothing happens.

```
d3.csv("data2.csv", type, function(error, data2) {  
    var wells = chart.selectAll(".well")
      .data(data2, function(d){ return d.well; })
      .transition().duration(1000)
      .attr("transform", function(d){ return "translate(" + projection([d.lng, d.lat])[0] + "," + projection([d.lng, d.lat])[1] + ")"; } );
});
```

When I change `well` back to `name` in `data2.csv`, the animation works find and the two dots transpose. Why do the field names have to be the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of how the [`key` argument to `data` function works](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-data). From the docs:

> ... the key function is invoked once for each element in the new data array, and once again for each existing element in the selection.

When it is called on the existing elements (which have data with field `name` and not `well`), it returns `undefined` and no nodes are selected for the update.

There are a couple of ways to correct this:

1. Rename the fields and make them consistent. Recommended: it makes maintaining the code easier.
2. Write the key function as: `.data(data2, function (d) { return d.well || d.name; })`. Less code, better for a one-off visualisation.